# Split "vendor" chunk using webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, code-splitting, commonschunkplugin

I have code splitting config similar to official [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#manifest-file)
and everything works perfect - all my node modules are in "vendor" chunk (including "babel-polyfill"). But now I need to move babel-polyfill and all it's dependecies to separate chunk ("polyfills") to be able to load it before my vendor bundle. Any ideas how to do that?

My config:

```
...
entry: {
  main: './index.jsx'
},
...
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'vendor',
  minChunks: function (module) {
    return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
  }
}),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'manifest' })
...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311513/webpack-2-supress-chunk-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Get dependencies

You can read the `package.json` from `babel-polyfill`

```
const path = require('path');
 
function getDependencies () {

       // Read dependencies...
       const { dependencies } = require('node_modules/babel-polyfill/package.json');

       // Extract module name
       return Object.keys(dependencies);
}
```

Just call it (should return an array with the `dependencies`):

```
const dependencies = getDependencies(); // ['module', ...]
```

## Detect polyfills

Check if module is `babel-polyfill` or dependency:

```
 function isPolyfill(module){
     
     // Get module name from path
     const name = path.posix.basename(module.context)              
    
     // If module has a path 
     return name &&

     // If is main module or dependency
     ( name === "babel-polyfill" || dependencies.indexOf(name) !== -1 ); 
 }
```

To remove `babel-polyfill` and dependencies just check if returns `false`

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    minChunks: function (module) {

        // If has path
        return module.context &&

        //If is a node-module
        module.context.indexOf('node_modules')!== -1 &&

        // Remove babel-polyfill and dependencies
        isPolyfill(module) === false;
    }
})
```

### Create polyfills chunk

To select only `babel-polyfill` and dependencies just check if returns `true`

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'polyfills',

    minChunks: function (module) {

        // If has a path
        return module.context &&

        //If is a node-module
        module.context.indexOf('node_modules')!== -1 &&

        // Select only  babel-polyfill and dependencies
        isPolyfill(module) === true;
    }
})
```

Comment: @EgorKomarov Please test this and report bugs / errors

Comment: @EgorKomarov if this answer helps you please mark as accepted, otherwise you should provide more details in your question

Comment: fix in `isPolyfill` func:

`return name && (name === "babel-polyfill" || dependencies.indexOf(name) !== -1);`
It's work if I creating only "vendor" **or** "polyfills" chunk, but how can I create them both at a time?

Comment: thanks, sorry I didn't test it, I'll fix it, try to create `polyfills` chunk first and then the vendor